# How to make iPhone host like a stream web server

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

By reference http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/,  I have get AVAssetReader,  how to create a url like "http:///a.mp3", so other machine can access this mp3 to download or play?

Comment: Could you please show code example, or some more suggestions to do this. I am intesrested in this topic. Thanks,

Comment: I use cocoahttpserver as file web server, and add some header , now can use medis player play m4a file <pre><code>- (NSDictionary *)httpHeaders
{
    NSString *key=@"Content-Type";

    NSString *value=@"audio/m4a";
    
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value, key, nil];
}</code></pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a connection, write this header

```
char * header = "ICY 200 OK\r\n"
"icy-name:iPhone FM\r\n"
"icy-url:http://iphone-fm.com/\r\n"
"content-type:audio/mpeg\r\n"
"\r\n";
```

then simply write the raw mp3 data down the socket.

I'm not sure if you want to serve the mp3 as a file, or as streaming radio. If as a file, you should probably set the content length. If as a radio stream, then you should check out

http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

and maybe implement streaming metadata for the song title, etc.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me which content-type is m4a file? I only can convert iPhone musci to this file. but audio/mpeg looks for mp3 file

Comment: It's audio/aac - but you can't stream the m4a file, you have to stream its ADTS AAC packets. Have a look at AudioFileReadPacketData or (better) skip all the intermediate steps by directly streaming the packets from an AVAssetReader. And start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial. Of course you could technically do it, since an iPhone has a full fledged TCP/IP stack. But, for a server you need to know its address before connecting to it.

What I've seen done in these cases is:

1. Turn on your APP
2. Show the URL to connect to based on its current address (you will probably be only able to connect through WIFI)
3. Use the client to connect to your **iPhone Server**.

Do keep in mind that this is extremely user unfriendly. You might want to consider a proxy server from your iPhone to the rest of the world in the middle.

Comment: thanks, but I am using asyncsocket to accept http request. My concern is how to send the music file as stream data to client.